# Interpreting numpy.where results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm confused by what the results of `numpy.where` mean, and how to use it to index into an array.

Have a look at the code sample below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(10,10,2)
indices = np.where(a[:,:,0] > 0.5)
```

I expect the `indices` array to be 2-dim and contain the indices where the condition is true. We can see that by

```
indices = np.array(indices)
indices.shape  # (2,120)
```

So it looks like `indices` is acting on the flattened array of some sort, but I'm not able to figure out exactly how. More confusingly,

```
a.shape  # (20,20,2)
a[indices].shape # (2,120,20,2)
```

**Question:**

How does indexing my array with the output of `np.where` actually *grow* the size of the array? What is going on here?

Comment: Just omit the line `indices = np.array(indices)`.  It turns the tuple you get into an array, which results in the indices being interpreted very differently when used in indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basing your indexing on a wrong assumption: `np.where` returns something that can be immediatly used for advanced indexing (it's a tuple of `np.ndarrays`). But you convert it to a numpy array (so it's now a `np.ndarray` of `np.ndarrays`).

So

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(10,10,2)
indices = np.where(a[:,:,0] > 0.5)
a[:,:,0][indices] 
# If you do a[indices] the result would be different, I'm not sure what
# you intended.
```

gives you the elements that are found by `np.where`. If you convert `indices` to a `np.array` it triggers another form of indexing ([see this section of the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays)) and the warning message in the [`docs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) gets very important. That's the reason why it increases the total size of your array.

---

Some additional information about what `np.where` means: You get a tuple containing `n` arrays. `n` is the number of dimensions of the input array. So the first element that satisfies the condition has index `[0][0], [1][0], ... [n][0]` and not `[0][0], [0][1], ... [0][n]`. So in your case you have (2, 120) meaning you have 2 dimensions and 120 found points.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I didn't realise I had to use it like `a[:,:,0][indices]`. But thinking about it, it kind of makes sense because `numpy.where` does give me an array that's longer than either of my first two dimensions.